# How to find path of find2perl script on Unix using bash or perl

Tags: perl, bash, unix, path

We (the company I work for) need to run the `find2perl` script on over a thousand different Unix servers of different flavors (Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX) and different versions.

The one thing that all the servers have in common, is that they all have at least one implementation of perl installed. However, not all systems have it configured the same way.

Finding the location of `perl` is easy enough using the `which` command. However, on 70% of the servers, the actual directory containing `find2perl` (the bin folder of perl) is not present in the `$PATH` variable and can't be located that way.

On some servers, `perl` is actually a symbolic link pointing another location, in which case I can use `ls -l` and `sed` to extract the target of the link to find where perl is actually installed.

On other servers however, it's more complicated, as it seems perl was compiled to a custom location and the binary of perl present in /bin or /usr/bin (or wherever perl is found) is not a symbolic link, but rather a full blown executable. In this case, I thought about using the `@INC` variable of perl to try to find `find2perl` but it seems rather excessive.

What would be the better/best/fullproof method (one-liner if possible) to always get the location of `find2perl` on a Unix system?

Comment: `find2perl` is just a platform independent perl script, so rather than trying to guess where it was installed on each system, why not just `scp` it to `/tmp` on the target systems?

Comment: We could, but I was hoping to avoid that if possible as it's an extra step that requires a file transfer.

Comment: You're already transferring your script that is calling find2perl, etc. right? Just embed it as a big heredoc if you can't find another way. Will update my answer with an example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ways to locate `find2perl`

Two ways, both of which rely on asking the perl install how it was configured:

### Config.pm

Its *probably* `scriptdirexp` from `Config.pm`.

```
$ perl -MConfig -E 'say $Config{scriptdirexp}'
/usr/bin
```

And indeed, that's where find2perl is on my system. You can `use Config;` in your perl scripts, which is its major advantage over the next method.

### perl -V:*varname*

As per [Yanick Girouard's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606627/yanick-girouard) comment, you can also use `perl -V:scriptdirexp` to get this, in a format suitable to passing to `eval` in a shell script. There are actually several formats available (so, you don't need to use e.g., cut to parse it):

```
OPTION                 OUTPUT (\n = actual newline)     NOTES
-V:scriptdirexp        scriptdirexp='/usr/bin';\n       full shell syntax, even if multiple -V options
-V:scriptdirexp:       scriptdirexp='/usr/bin'          trailing colon omits semicolon and newline 
-V::scriptdirexp       '/usr/bin'; \n                   extra leading colon omits var= part
-V::scriptdirexp:      '/usr/bin'                       you can combine them.
```

Full documentation is in the [`perlrun` manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

## Ways to embed `find2perl`

If you decide to copy over `find2perl`, as per [evil otto's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796950/evil-otto) comment, you can actually do that by embedding it in your shell script. There are many ways. If neither of the two below work, then you can certainly use `shar` (which has an extremely long history, and is likely compatible with everything).

### Quoted here-document

The easiest way is if your shell supports quoted here-documents. They all should, as its [a POSIX requirement](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04):

```
#!/bin/sh
perl - -name 'foo' -mtime 2 -print <<'FIND2PERL'
#!/usr/bin/perl
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
      if $running_under_some_shell;
⋮
FIND2PERL
```

### Hex dump in a non-quoted here-document

If some of your shells don't implement quoted here-documents ([POSIX‽ what's that!](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04)), then you have to protect find2perl from shell expansion. An easy way is to hex dump it, as 0–9 and a–f are all safe from shell expansion. The dump is easily done with `xxd -p /usr/bin/find2perl`, which only requires `xxd` on one machine. To read back the dump, you can use plain perl:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -n -e 'chomp; print pack("H*", $_)' <<HEX | perl - -name 'foo'
23212f7573722f62696e2f7065726c0a202020206576616c202765786563
202f7573722f62696e2f7065726c202d5320243020247b312b222440227d
⋮
HEX
```

### Using `find2perl` several times

Naturally, with either approach, you could also write find2perl to a temporary file (if you need to invoke it multiple times, for example). You could also embed it in a shell function.

Comment: I've seen cases in my environment, where perl was present as binary in /usr/bin/, but where the actual perl5 bin folder was in /opt/perl5... There was no symlink leading me there either, I found it by searching for find2perl... Would this return /opt/perl5/bin or the directory where the perl executable is in?

Comment: This seems to work for me: `$(perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{scriptdirexp}')/find2perl`. I can use this to test the existence of `find2perl`. I will try it on non-standard perl installs tomorrow to see if it works in every case, and if so we have the winner!

Comment: @YanickGirouard: Config.pm is generated as part of the perl configure/build process, so it should always work. Unless someone has gone around with `mv` after doing make install. Or has installed two different perls in a conflicting manner. But if someone has done that, nothing short a SHA-256 check of every file on the filesystem will be able to find it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you point me to some doc on how to use the hex dump method you mentioned?

Comment: @YanickGirouard: Well, basically, you'd use a normal (non-quoted) here-document with a hex dump (e.g., from xxd -p). That'd be subject to shell expansion, but of course 0-9A-F is safe from the shell. Then pipe that to your favorite un-hex-dump utility (which may very well be a perl one-liner involving pack). Then pipe that to perl. `xxd -p -r <<HEX | perl - -name 'foo' \n 23212f75... \n HEX`. That's using `xxd` to un-hex-dump, but no reason that couldn't be `perl -n -e 'chomp; print pack("H*", $_)'`.

Comment: Thanks. A little out of my comfort zone in terms of what I'm used to, but I'll give it a thought and read up on it. However, if it turns out that `$(perl -MConfig -e 'print $Config{scriptdirexp}')/find2perl` does find find2perl on at least 95% of our servers, then it will be the solution. We can handle the 5% separately if we have to.

Comment: Found a shorter command-line to get the variable's value: `perl -V:scriptdirexp | cut -d"'" -f2`

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update my answer to include -V as you found, and also include the hex method.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the added info (-V::scriptdirexp: seems to be what I need)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lwe '$_ = $^X; s/perl$/find2perl/; -f or die qq($_ not -f); print'
```

Copy the interpreter executable path into dollar default argument. Patch the value, assuming that `find2perl` is in the same directory as `perl` itself. (This is specified as UNIX only, so you don't have to cater for `perl.exe`, which would be easy enough to deal with.) Then test the file exists, and `die` if it doesn't. (You might invent some better error handling.) Then print the path if we're still alive. That's it.

Okay, here's a version that works for Windows, too:

```
perl -lwe "$_ = $^X; s/perl(\.exe)?$/find2perl/;
  -f or -f qq($_.bat) or die qq($_ not -f); print"
```

Note the double quotes, de rigueur on Windows for `cmd.exe`. And it has to go on one line, I just wrapped it for readability.

Comment: This seems to work well too, but I will need to test it on non-standard installations of perl tomorrow to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Perl doesn't have to be in the same directory as find2perl. There are even configuration options when you build perl that'd result in them not being in the same.

Comment: @derobert, there might be some whacky configurability, but I have never observed its effects in the wild. So I'd consider that to be esoteric fringe systems and esoteric configurations ... but YMMV.

Comment: @Lumi: Well, if you read OP's 5th paragraph ("on other servers however…"), apparently OP has this configuration in the wild. I'm pretty sure Configure asks you when you build perl; nothing special is required.